# TypeError: this.web3.eth.getMaxPriorityFeePerGas is not a function

Tags: web3js

https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/guides/eip-1559/maxpriorityfeepergas-vs-maxfeepergas#lets-see-them-in-action

```
web3.eth.estimateGas({
  to: toAddress,
  data: "0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"
}).then((estimatedGas) => {
  web3.eth.getMaxPriorityFeePerGas().then((tip) => {
    web3.eth.getBlock("pending").then((block) => {
      const baseFee = Number(block.baseFeePerGas);
      const max = Number(tip) + baseFee - 1; // less than the sum

      sendTx(web3, {
        gas: estimatedGas,
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: Number(tip),
        maxFeePerGas: max,
        to: toAddress,
        value: 100,
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Can anyone help me?

**Error:**

```
TypeError: web3.eth.getMaxPriorityFeePerGas is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution [here](https://githublab.com/repository/issues/alchemyplatform/alchemy-web3/115).

```
import { createAlchemyWeb3 } from "@alch/alchemy-web3";

const alch = createAlchemyWeb3('https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/demo');
alch.eth.getMaxPriorityFeePerGas().then(console.log);
```

In your case code will look like

```
import { createAlchemyWeb3 } from "@alch/alchemy-web3";

const alch = createAlchemyWeb3('https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/demo');
web3.eth.estimateGas({
  to: toAddress,
  data: "0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"
}).then((estimatedGas) => {
  alch.eth.getMaxPriorityFeePerGas().then((tip) => {
    web3.eth.getBlock("pending").then((block) => {
      const baseFee = Number(block.baseFeePerGas);
      const max = Number(tip) + baseFee - 1; // less than the sum

      sendTx(web3, {
        gas: estimatedGas,
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: Number(tip),
        maxFeePerGas: max,
        to: toAddress,
        value: 100,
      });
    });
  });
});
```